# "need finit ylim values" Problem to plot a database in Shiny (R) with inputfile

Tags: r, plot, shiny

Im trying to plot a database in shiny, but i want to upload a database with inputfile of shiny. When i plot my database with these lines:

```r
 Resumen<-read.xlsx("vectores.xlsx")
 plot.ts(Resumen)
```

it plots well. However, when i try to plot the same by upload the database with input$file1 there is this mistake "need finit ylim values". Here is my code and thank you for your time.

````r
library(shiny)

ui = fluidPage(
  
  titlePanel("plotprueba"),
 
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel( 
  
      fileInput("file1", "label", accept = ".xlsx")
  ),
    mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(type="tab",
        
                  tabPanel("Grafica", plotOutput("plot1"))
                  
                  
      )
    )
  )
)

server = function(input, output,session) {
  

   
    output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
      
     
      #setwd ("C:/Users/Usuario/Desktop") 
      #Resumen<-read.xlsx("vectores.xlsx")
      inFile <- input$file1
    
      plot.ts(inFile)

  })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)```
````

Comment: I tried to replace with your tip but there is this mistake `path` must be a string

Comment: Can you try  `read.xlsx(paste0(inFile$datapath, ".xlsx"))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can change the `server` to

```
server = function(input, output,session) {
  
  
  
  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    
    req(input$file1)
    
    inFile <- input$file1
    
    plot.ts(read.xlsx(inFile$datapath))
    
  })
  
}
```